# Formula for the interior product of a p-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

Let $X: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector field and let $$\omega = \sum_{i_1 < \dots < i_p} f_{i_1\dots i_p} dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_p}$$ be a $p$-form over $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am interested in a formula for the interior product $i_X\omega$.

(Choose $n=3$ and $X(x,y,z) = (z,y,-x)$ for all examples below.)

### $p = 1$:

\begin{align}
\omega &= \sum_i f_i dx_i &\Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega &= \sum_i f_iX_i\\
\omega &= dx + zdy + zdz &\Rightarrow \quad i_X \omega &= X_x + zX_y + zX_z\\
& & &= z + yz - xz
\end{align}

### $p = 2$:

\begin{align}
\omega &= \sum_{i < j} f_{ij} dx_i \wedge dx_j &\Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega &= \sum_{i < j} f_{ij} \left( X_i dx_j - X_j dx_i \right)\\
\omega &= dx \wedge dy + dx \wedge dz &\Rightarrow \quad i_X \omega &= X_xdy - X_ydx + X_xdz - X_zdx\\
& & &= zdy - ydx + zdz + xdx \\
& & &= \left( x - y \right)dx + zdy + zdz
\end{align}

### $p = 3$:

\begin{align}
\omega &= \sum_{i < j < k} f_{ijk} dx_i \wedge dx_j \wedge dx_k &&\Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega =\ ???\\
\omega &= 2zdx \wedge dy \wedge dz &&\Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega =\ ???
\end{align}

## Questions

1. Are my formulas and examples for $p=1$ and $p=2$ correct?
2. What is the formula for $p \geq 3$?

Comment: See [this Phy SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/575999/203278) of mine for an overview of how the interior product formula works. I'm sure you can piece together a formula (and simplify it as much as you like) based on what I've written there (though for the sake of concrete calculations, such formulas aren't that useful; it's better to learn how to apply the various rules, such as linearity and 'product' rules).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I like your Phy SE answer, because it goes into great detail, but the lack of (easy) examples makes it hard for me to follow. Can you please show how to apply your Phy SE answer to the $p=3$ example?

Comment: instead, how about you plug in the formulas shown there for the special case $p=3$, and I'll tell you if you're on the right track

Comment: @peek-a-boo Here is my best guess:
\begin{align}
i_X\omega =\ &2z \left( X_x dy \wedge dz - X_y dx \wedge dz + X_z dx \wedge dy \right)\\
=\ &2z \left( zdy \wedge dz - ydx \wedge dz - xdx \wedge dy \right)\\
=\ &-2xzdx\wedge dy - 2yzdx\wedge dz + 2z^2dy\wedge dz
\end{align}

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. Notice that what you're essentially doing is looking at the $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ in $\omega$ and replacing each 1-form with the corresponding component of the vector field (and alternating with signs). So indeed $\iota_X(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)=+ X_x\wedge dy\wedge dz - dx\wedge X_y\wedge dz + dx\wedge dy\wedge X_z$. Of course the wedge product of a function with a form is defined to be just usual multiplication, so we get $X_x\,dy\wedge dz-X_y\,dx\wedge dz+X_z\,dx\wedge dy$. And since $\omega=2z\,dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$, you multiply overall by $2z$ exactly as you did.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Does the following formula for $p=3$ hold?
$$i_X\omega =  \sum_{i < j < k} f_{ijk} \left( X_i dx_j \wedge dx_k - X_j dx_i \wedge dx_k + X_k dx_i \wedge dx_j \right)$$
What about this messy formula for a general $p$? (The $\hat{}$ means the term is omitted.)
$$i_X\omega = \sum_{i_1 < \dots < i_p} f_{i_1\dots i_p} \sum_{j=1}^p (-1)^{j-1} X_{i_j} dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_{j-1}} \wedge \hat{dx_{i_j}} \wedge dx_{i_{j+1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_p}$$

Comment: @WilfredMontoya I saw your comment after posting my answer. Yes, your formulas seem to be correct.

Comment: yes, that's right (the sum over all $i_1<\dots <i_p$ is the expected stuff. The important thing is you alternate in signs and replace each $1$-form by its value on the vector field $X$ i.e $\sum_{j=1}^p(-1)^{j-1}dx^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_j}(X)\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_p}$, or recalling what the wedge product of functions with forms means, and using that $dx^{i_j}(X)=X^{i_j}$, we get as you wrote $\sum_{j=1}^p(-1)^{j-1}X^{i_j}\,dx^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \widehat{dx^{i_j}}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_p}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas and examples for $p=1$ and $p=2$ are correct.

### $p = 3$:

\begin{align}
\omega &= \sum_{i < j < k} f_{ijk} dx_i \wedge dx_j \wedge dx_k\\
\Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega &= \sum_{i < j < k} f_{ijk} \left( X_i dx_j \wedge dx_k - X_j dx_i \wedge dx_k + X_k dx_i \wedge dx_j \right)\\\\
\omega &= 2zdx \wedge dy \wedge dz\\
\Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega &= 2z\left( X_x dy \wedge dz - X_y dx \wedge dz + X_z dx \wedge dy \right)\\
&= 2z\left( zdy \wedge dz - ydx \wedge dz - xdx \wedge dy \right)\\
&= -2xzdx\wedge dy - 2yzdx \wedge dz + 2z^2dy\wedge dz
\end{align}

### $p \in \mathbb{N}$:

\begin{align}
\omega &= \sum_{i_1 < \dots < i_p} f_{i_1\dots i_p} dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_p} \\
\Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega &= \sum_{i_1 < \dots < i_p} f_{i_1\dots i_p} \sum_{j=1}^p (-1)^{j-1} X_{i_j} dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_{j-1}} \wedge dx_{i_{j+1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_p}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

For $p = 3$:
$$\omega = \sum_{i < j < k} f_{ijk} dx_i \wedge dx_j \wedge dx_k \quad \Rightarrow \quad i_X\omega =\ \sum_{i < j < k} f_{ijk} (X_i dx_j \wedge dx_k - X_j dx_i \wedge dx_k + X_k dx_i \wedge dx_j)$$

Generally, let $\omega$ be a $k$-form $\alpha_1 \wedge \alpha_2 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_k$, where $\alpha_i$'s are $1$-forms and $X$ be vector field. Then, $$i_X\omega = \sum_{i=1}^{k} (-1)^{i-1} \alpha_i(X)\cdot\alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{i-1}\wedge\alpha_{i+1}\wedge\dots\alpha_k$$