# Symbol $⌋$ in differential geometry, as in $(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)⌋R$

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, differential-forms

I was reading a text about differential geometry and I noticed this example:

$xdy\wedge dz+ydz\wedge dx+zdx\wedge dy = (dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)⌋R$

where $R:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3, R(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$.

I don't quite get the meaning of the symbol $⌋$ since my class hasn't covered this, would anyone like to add some detail?

Comment: Was the symbol $\lrcorner$ rather than $\rfloor$, perhaps?

Comment: @Kajelad I think the two can be used interchangeably. No matter.

Comment: $\lrcorner$ is often used to denote the [interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product). The typographical difference is only minor, but I think \lrcorner is preferred to \rfloor.

Comment: Also, I think it's much more standard to put the vector field on the left, so $R\lrcorner (dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)$ means the interior product $\iota_R(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo would you like to show the computation that makes the equality hold? I cannot find any other example.

Comment: See [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4415411/568204) where interior products were discussed in great length for example.